# Google Cloud App Engine + H2 persistent + Spring boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, h2

I try to deploy my spring rest application on app engine, it utilizes a simple database H2, but when my application started on app engine there is :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file "/srv/data" [90062-196]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException (DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get (DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get (DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.createDirectory (FilePathDisk.java:274)
at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectory (FileUtils.java:42)
at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories (FileUtils.java:309)
at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile (FileLock.java:342)
at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock (FileLock.java:135)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open (Database.java:662)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase (Database.java:276)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init> (Database.java:270)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession (Engine.java:64)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession (Engine.java:176)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate (Engine.java:154)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession (Engine.java:137)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession (Engine.java:27)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer (SessionRemote.java:354)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init> (JdbcConnection.java:116)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init> (JdbcConnection.java:100)
at org.h2.Driver.connect (Driver.java:69)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection (DriverDataSource.java:138)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection (PoolBase.java:354)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry (PoolBase.java:202)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry (HikariPool.java:473)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast (HikariPool.java:554)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init> (HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection (HikariDataSource.java:112)
```

And there is my application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/planningDb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I'm wondering if I have the right to write in H2 file in app Engine;

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[App Engine limits the directories you can write to](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features) depending on which runtime you are using, so in GAE standard you cannot write outside of /tmp. Also keep in mind that having the database in the GAE instances will create a database created for each instance and the content will be lost each time the instance is deleted/restarted.

I would recommend you to use one of the [Cloud SQL options](https://cloud.google.com/sql) or [create a GCE instance for the database](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql), you can avoid losing the data. If you choose to use a GCE instance you will have to maintain it yourself, Cloud SQL instances are Google managed.